# How to find the equation for a manifold of a nonlinear dynamical system?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, manifolds, stability-in-odes, nonlinear-dynamics

I have the following 2-D dynamical system:

$\dot{y} = -y^2$, and $\dot{x} = y$

We can linearize the system, and find the eigenvectors that represent the manifolds. In this case, one of the eigenvectors is $(1,0)$ and the other is non-unique.

My question is: how can the manifolds be represented in equation form in this context? Or phrased differently, what are the equations of the (stable or unstable) manifolds?

Thank you

Comment: Stable and unstable manifolds *at which equilibrium point*? Anyway, you can simply solve the system explicitly.

Comment: There is one equilibrium point: (0,0). It is indeed possible to solve the system explicitly, but I am looking for the connection between the eigenvector(s) of the system and the equation of the manifold(s). The explicit solution does not tell me this unfortunately.

Comment: No, there are *infinitely* many: $(x,0)$ is an equilibrium for every $x$! (And since the equilibria are not isolated, they are not hyperbolic, so you can't expect to learn too much about the system from the linearization alone.)